# which is the correct way while using props in functional component in react

Tags: reactjs, components, react-component

which one is the correct way in react functional component and why?

Way 1:

```
export function renderElements(props) {

   let { value, element } = props;
   return (
     <!--- Code----!>
   )
}

renderElements.defaultProps = {
   value: 0,
   element: 'Hello'
}
```

Way 2

```
export function renderElements({
   value = 0,
   element = 'Hello'
}) {
   return (
     <!--- Code----!>
   )
}
```

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 2):

There's no correct way, both ways can acceptable, depending on a case. The difference is that objects (`<b>hi</b>` is React element, which is an object) will be same with `defaultProps`. This may result in undesirable behaviour if prop values are mutated by a component:

```
export function renderElements(props) {
   let { value, element } = props;
   element.props.children = value; // affects all renderElements instances at once

   return element;
}

renderElements.defaultProps = {
   value: 0,
   element: <b>hi</b>
}
```

This may be not a problem if objects are immutable (`React.cloneElement` in case of React element), which is preferable way to do things in React.

Comment: thanks for your post but the passing element is not a problem I have changed now. both have been acceptable but which is the better practice and good code?

Comment: This is totally a matter of preference. As I noted, the main difference is that object default values are new on each function call in second case, which is a good practice. But this doesn't matter if you don't mutate objects, which is another good practice. In the last edit you removed `<b>` element, and there's no difference if props are scalar values.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are correct. But for me, the second way is better because I am using it also code looks cool. You can initialize values in that case just to avoid code breaking and you are not receiving expected values

instead of using the function key wort, it's better to use es6 syntax for functional components.

```
`export const renderElements = ({
   value = 0,
   element = <b>hi</b>
 }) => {
   return (
     <!--- Code----!>
   )
 }`
```

or if you want to return only a single element or object you can use shorter syntax like:

```
`export const renderElements = ({
   value = 0,
   element = <b>hi</b>
}) => <!--- Code----!>`
```